# How to get latitude and longitude of poiner located on Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently using Google API to point the position on Google map.

this is `google-maps-utility-library-v3`

with the link

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html
```

I wrote this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {
        var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);
        var myMapOptions = {
             zoom: 15
            ,center: secheltLoc
            ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: theMap,
            draggable: true,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
            visible: true
        });
    }
    function getLatLong(){
    var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);
        var myMapOptions = {
             zoom: 15
            ,center: secheltLoc
            ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: theMap,
            draggable: true,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
            visible: true
        });
    infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: marker.getPosition()});
    <!--  var getLat = new InfoBox(); -->
     alert(InfoBox.prototype.getPosition);
    }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:50%"></div>
   <input type="button" onclick="getLatLong();" />
   <div id="letLong"></div>
```

What I want is when I click this `getLatLong()` function I must get currently positioned markers latitude longitude.

Please Help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var marker=null;

    function initialize()
    {
        var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);
        var myMapOptions = {
            zoom:15, center:secheltLoc, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:theMap,
            draggable:true,
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
            visible:true
        });
    }
    function getLatLong()
    {
        alert(marker.position);
    }
</script>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: thanks ,can we get the address of this lat long using the same api?.

Comment: Use geocoder https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder